# parseInt returns NaN ( js )

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var serviceB = document.getElementById('service').value;

var service = parseInt(serviceB, 10);

function showMessage() {
  alert(service);
  alert(typeof(service)); //returns number
}
```

```html
<label for="service">Number of services</label>
<input type="text" id="service" name="service" min="1" max="10" required="required">
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showMessage()">
```

I want to take the number of services to do a **FOR** loop, and when i test the alert function it returns **NaN**...
I also tried it without the ",10" but it does the same thing.
can anyone please help me ?

Comment: What is the value of `serviceB` you're trying to parse?

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `serviceB` before passing it to `parseInt`?

Comment: _"can anyone please help me ?"_ - The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will do so: _Return value -> An integer parsed from the given string. Or `NaN` when the radix is smaller than 2 or bigger than 36, or, **the first non-whitespace character cannot be converted to a number**_

Comment: There's no [mcve] so this is just a guess... Move `var serviceB = ...; var service = ...;` into `showMessage()`

Comment: @VLAZ it is the value of the <input> with id 'service' ...  

var serviceB = document.getElementById('service').value;

Comment: @JennyPrs that's it - what value do you put in there? Also, are you sure you're taking the value *after* it was written?

Answer (score 2):

Please use `<input type="number">`. If you type something that is not a number (e. g. 5f), then it will return NaN.